# How to use fcrackzip on multiple cores?

Tags: 18.04, zip

By default fcrackzip uses only one core/thread. Is it possible to split the task on several processes?

Answer (score 1):

Found [this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/shikendon/50879d10594bb8537d85e4b8e72fcf8c) which seems to achieve exactly what you want to do:

Feeding multple instances of fcrackzip using xargs:

```
logfile=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).log
targetfile=test.zip

# Start 1 processes for cracking mixalpha-numeric maximum 5 digits
fcrackzip -c Aa1 -b -l 1-5 --verbose -u $targetfile & >> $logfile &

# Start 62 processes for cracking mixalpha-numeric equal to 6 digits
eval echo\ {A..Z}AAAAA\; | xargs -I % -P 26 fcrackzip -c Aa1 -b -p % --verbose -u 
$targetfile >> $logfile &
eval echo\ {a..z}AAAAA\; | xargs -I % -P 26 fcrackzip -c Aa1 -b -p % --verbose -u 
$targetfile >> $logfile &
eval echo\ {0..9}AAAAA\; | xargs -I % -P 10 fcrackzip -c Aa1 -b -p % --verbose -u 
$targetfile >> $logfile &

tail -F $logfile | grep FOUND
```

Comment: as noted by a gist comment: If you run line 8 and look at top it just spawns 26 threads doing the same thing.